# Comboboxes, datacontexts and databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, datacontext

Just getting confused when trying to display certain things when utilising itemssource, datacontexts and binding.

```
public class Date
{
    public DateTime _WeekDate;
    public ICollectionView _WeekData;
}

public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ICollectionView WeekDates { get; private set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        List<Date> _dates = new List<Date>();

        //Code to populate _dates

        WeekDates = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_dates);
    }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    gMain.DataContext = _ViewModel;
}
```

So as you can see I've got a collection of a class called Date, which has a DateTime and another collection inside it. This is all created in a ViewModel which is attached to a grid as a data context.

Within this grid I have a combobox which needs to display the DateTime value listed in each Date class within the collection. So with much messing about I have this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PickupDates}" DisplayMemberPath="WeekDate" />
```

This has worked however I also want a binding converter to be applied to the MemberPath to change the style in which the date will be displayed. But applying it this way I can't add the Converter. To no avail, I've tried things such as:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PickupDates}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=WeekDate", Converter={StaticResource DateFormatter}/>
```

Any ideas? Or any better ways of doing this?

Thanks in advance,
SumGuy

Comment: Code seems incoherent. The class `Date` is never used.

Comment: What type of the PickupDates property? Should it be in the MainWindowViewModel class?

Comment: Sorry about that. Hope edit helps. WeekDates is a collection which uses a list of Date objects as it's source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind to the DisplayMemberPath but what you can do is provide a property within your bound object, similar to WeekDate in the working example you provided, that returns the WeekDate in the format you wish.  When WeekDate is set, raise the propertychanged event for the new formatting property.

Comment: OK I get what you're saying and yes that would be an easier way of doing it (as always I like to make things difficult for myself). But just to confirm your other point, you can't bind to DisplayMemberPath. Is this right? And why is this?

Comment: I think the "Path" used is confusing.  DisplayMemberPath is simply the name of the property to use not a value to use.  Not sure why Microsoft went this direction because it's very Windows Form like.  I've seen some posts where people have found ways around this using DataTemplates, but for your situation, it just seems like a lot of extra work to do something that is easily solved with an additional property.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the other answer is to set the [ItemStringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemstringformat.aspx) to the DateTime format that you want to display.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PickupDates}" 
          ItemStringFormat="ddd dd-MM-yyyy" 
          DisplayMemberPath="WeekDate" /
```